# Parsing web-page with beautifulsoup not showing full results

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

[image]

I'm trying to pull information inside the 'LotusPersonInfo' tag, which has information of people in (p) tags, which I shouldn't have a problem extracting. My issue is that when I print the results of beautiful soup, it only shows main containers div but not the elements/tables inside.So basically, I want to get the text inside 'lotusPersonInfo'. Cannot post actual site link since the company's site requires authentication.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('user','pass')

site= 'http://companysite.com'

page = session.get(site).text

soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "resultContainer"})

for x in divTag:
    print(x)
    
print(soup)
```

output:

```
</div>
<div id="contentContainer">
<div class="contentBodyContainer" id="profiles">
<!-- start render_para_override -->
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("breadcrumb").style.display="none"</script>
<div style=" margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 275px;"><a </div>
<div id="searchResults">
<div id="resultsCol1">
<div id="resultsListContainer"></div>
</div>
<div id="resultCol2">
<div id="resultContainer"></div>
<div id="reportsChainContainer"></div>
</div>
<div id="searchLinksContainer">
```

[image: Inside LotusPersonInfo]

Inside LotusPersonInfo^

Comment: from your output it looks as if it's not selecting the div's with the id you specified.  I would changing it to `divTag = soup.find_all("div", id="resultContainer")` and try running it again.  Or based on your update `divTag = soup.find_all("div", class_="lotusPersonalInfo")`

Comment: I tried that, and when I print in the for loop and remove the outer print, I get this as the result.  <div id="resultContainer"></div>. I tried ur 2nd option by doing class_='lotusPersonalInfo" and I got no output.

Comment: Can you update your post to show what's inside of the `class='lotusPersonalInfo'`?

Comment: @Phillip just did